# Read whitespace-split words from text file and put into array in shell

Tags: arrays, shell

I'm trying to read text from a file and then put this in an array split by spaces. I've been trying to follow examples online but my string still appears to not be being split correctly into the array.

```
    nameList=$(cat "test.txt")
    echo $nameList
    array=($nameList)
    echo $array
    echo $array[1]
```

Which just returns the result

```
    this is a test
    this
    this[1]
```

As you can see only the first word is being captured by the variable array.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `array=( $nameList )` is a common idiom, but one that invites bugs: Look at what it does if your `test.txt` contains a `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read just one line, split by spaces:

```
read -r -a array <test.txt
```

...or to read until the first NUL in the file or its end:

```
read -r -d '' -a array <test.txt
```

---

To access an element of that array:

```
echo "${array[1]}"
```

...or better (reliably functional even in [cases where the specification for `echo` is ambiguous](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), such as if your word is `-n` or contains backslash literals):

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[1]}"
```